# Delphi FMX debugging Android 64-bit apps shows strings as pointer

Tags: android, delphi, debugging, 64-bit, firemonkey

I use Delphi 10.4.2 for development of an Android app. The 32-bit version of my app is running without problems. But the 64-bit version cannot find my deployed application files. To get the path of the data the following statement is used:

```pascal
path := TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim;
 
// --> '/data/user/0/solutions.kloss.ZaxxonV2/files/'  <-- on 32-bit system
```

When I try to check the content of `path` in the 64-bit environment with the integrated debugger, it shows only the 64-bit address of the string, not the content. So debugging is impossible. 32-bit debugger works fine.

How can the debugger be configured for 64-bit? Does the `path` variable point to different places when using 64-bit?

Comment: Do you have all of the 10.4.2 patches installed, including the ones that were [just released](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/rad-studio-10-4-2-general-patch-and-delphi-compiler-patch/) a few days ago?

Comment: I installed yesterday and Delphi help says: Update 2 is installed.

Comment: There are some patches available since april ,30. - but only  for users with an active update subscription. I use a test version 30 days. Any chance to implement the patches?

Comment: https://www.embarcadero.com/update-subscription: "*Can I obtain updates and hotfixes without a subscription? An active update subscription is the only way to obtain updates and hotfixes.*"

Comment: Normally I use Delphi Community Edition 10.3.3. Deploying 64-bit apps to Google store is ok. But the apps run only on devices with Android up to 9. On devices with Android 10 and 11 the apps stop during start without any message. Because there is no CE version 10.4 available, I installed Delphi 10.4.2. trial for 30 days. Now the problems occur as mentioned before. Therfore my development comes to an unsatisfied end. If fundamental functions are not working the trial version makes no sense.

Comment: @PeterKloß The 64bit versions of your 32bit apps will work exactly the same unless you have 64bit-specific code. So your development hasn't come to an end. Keep going.

Comment: @nolaspeaker What if OP has only a device with 64 bit OS installed on it. In that case OP is forced into testing his application as 64 bit not as 32 bit. So yeah I can feel OP being frustrated about this.

Comment: @nolaspeaker. Google Play Store expects an aab package with 32 and 64-bit code. Before I put apps on the Google Playstore, I have to test both versions of the app. Anything else would be irresponsible. And there seem to be differences, as the uploaded app-specific files are not found in the 64-bit version.

Comment: I found the error with file not found on Android 64-bit. FMX ignores the case of the filenames on all Windows systems and Android 32-bit. TEST.TXT and test.txt are found on Android 32-bit, but on Android 64-bit the filenames have to be specified case sensitive as normally on Android. I was not aware of this behavior. I don’t know if it’s on purpose.